# Problemas com JOIN e nas CONDIÇÕES - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tendo que buscar em 2 `table` alguns dados com certas condições, segue a situação:

`table`: **tbTransito** => `Colunas`:
**Codigo - Qtd - NumPedido**
`table`: **tbEstoque** => `Colunas`:
**Codigo - Qtd - QtdLimite**

Minha query deve retornar as `colunas` **Código**, (**Qtd**(tbEstoque) + **Qtd**,(tbTransito)), **QtdLim**
sempre que (**Qtd**(tbEstoque) + **Qtd**,(tbTransito)) <= **QtdLim**

Porém cada `row`deve somar as **Qtd**s apenas se os **Codigo**s forem os mesmo  e se em **NumPedido**  = 0

**-- Codigo  --  Qtd  --  NumPedido --**
---- M01 ------ 5 ---------- 0 -----------
---- M02 ------ 2 ---------- 0 -----------
---- M03 ------ 4 -------- INV2 --------

**-- Codigo -- Qtd -- QtdLim --**
---- M01 ------ 2 -------- 5 -------
---- M02 ------ 3 -------- 5 -------
---- M03 ------ 3 -------- 5 -------
---- M04 ------ 1 -------- 5 -------
---- M02 ------ 1 -------- 5 ------

Em uma situação como esta acima o retorno seria apenas :

**-- Codigo -- Qtd -- QtdLim --**
---- M03 ------ 3 -------- 5 -------
---- M04 ------ 1 -------- 5 -------

Estou tentando o seguinte código :

```
    select e.Codigo, 
           SUM(e.Qtd) + t.Qtd, 
           e.QtdLim 
    from tbEstoque e join tbTransito t on t.Codigo = e.Codigo 
    AND SUM(e.Qtd) + t.Qtd <= e.QtdLim 
    AND e.NumPedido = 0
```

Porem não está retornando certo.

Comment: tente usar um where depois do join da coluna ao inves de and diretamente

...`from tbEstoque e join tbTransito t on t.Codigo = e.Codigo where SUM(e.Qtd) + t.Qtd <= e.QtdLim ...`

Comment: mostre também como o retorno está vindo, se puder

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes o retorno continua sendo o mesmo erro. - error#1111 - Invalid use of group function, o que me leva a crer que é culpa do SUM(), pois ao tirar ele a query retorna resultados: 2 rows  => ** m02 / 5 / 5** e outra m02 / 3 / 5

Comment: `group by e.codigo, e.qtdeLim`
coloca abaixo do codigo sql

Answer (score 0):

Quando se usa funcão de agregação(`sum, max, min, count`) na consulta, precisa de um `group by`

```
select e.Codigo, 
           SUM(e.Qtd + t.Qtd), 
           e.QtdLim 
    from tbEstoque e join tbTransito t on t.Codigo = e.Codigo 
    where SUM(e.Qtd + t.Qtd) <= e.QtdLim 
    AND e.NumPedido = 0
    group by e.Codigo, e.QtdLim
```